# How can I assign a height to an element, such that the height is equal to the height of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a `<section>` which has some content inside it.

```
<section class="Header">
    <h1 class="mainHeader">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet con</h1>
    <h3 class="subHeader">obcaecati laboriosam iste ad exercitationem culpa aspernatur, molestias</h3>
</section>
```

I have given some `CSS` to all the `subclasses` of `Header`. Just to make them look good. `Header` should be the height of the screen. Because at every viewport font-size of all `subclasses` will change.

For now, I have given `subHeader` `margin-bottom` to make `Header` of the `screen` `size`. But that is a wrong practice because I need to change the `margin-bottom` of the `subHeader` every time and for every `viewport`. Plus at many `screen` `sizes`, it may be shorter or longer than the `screen`.

When I assign the `media query` to make the website responsive. For smaller screen sizes, eg: (max-width: 768px) I reduced the `size` of the `text`, and the `header` moves up, but I want it to be always the `height` of the device and not change its `height` even is the `font-size` is increased or decreased.

---

***I have searched the web and got some solutions:***

**First:** Use `height: 100vh;`

**Second:** By `Javascript`(code below)

```
var vHeight = $(window).height(),
  header= $('.Header');

header.css({
  "height": vHeight
});
```

---

#### But both of them are not working on smaller screen sizes. The height of the `Header` is longer than the screen size.

---

*Wrap Up:*

> ***Main Question:*** How can I assign a height to an element, such that the height is equal to the height of the screen(which is being used at that time of viewing the website)?

---

Do anybody know how to do so?

Comment: What do you mean "not working on small viewports"? `100vh` is _always_ the height of the viewport (browser window).

Comment: @CalvinNunes I edited the comment

Comment: *"But both of them are not working on smaller viewports."*  Can you explain to us why it is not working? In which browsers are you testing? In which devices? Desktop, mobile?

Comment: May you show a [mcve]? We're pretty much guessing the solution at the moment.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I have updated the question.

Comment: @CalvinNunes: I have updated the question.

Comment: (May you also include some CSS as that's probably where the answer lies?)

Comment: that is just colour and simple properties

Comment: if it is longer than than the screen size it is probably because some of its content is forcing it to be longer... a [mcve] could be useful here. But anyway, I keep asking: which browsers are you testing? In which devices? Desktop, mobile?

Comment: @fdzczxc how are you getting to smaller screens? Please provide a minimal reproducible example so we can better help you.

Comment: When I assign the `media query` to make the website responsive. For smaller screen sizes, eg: (max-width: 768px) I reduced the `size` of the `text`, and the `header` moves up, but I want it to be always the `height` of the device and not change its `height` even is the `font-size` is increased or decreased.

Comment: @CalvinNunes: Google Chrome, Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

To get the screen's height you can use the [Window.screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen) object, where you have several properties available to you like `screen.height` and `screen.width`.

For example, this will give you the screen's height in a variable:

```js
let screenHeight = window.screen.height;
```

Now you can use that height to dynamically/programmatically change whatever you need with the exact height of the screen. For example, setting an element's height:

```js
let yourElement = document.getElementById('elementsId');
yourElement.style.height = screenHeight;
```

**edit**

You could also try to get the view port height with [window.innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) because it's based of the viewport's width:

```js
let viewHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

that should play better with your media queries, although you may need to tweak a few pixels.

---

Be careful when using hard coded width's and height's. They can look great on one screen size, but break all the others. Try to stick with percentage based sizing and using things like the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model) and [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for your layouts when responsiveness is a concern.

Comment: Would the screen's height dynamically change?

Comment: @evolutionxbox not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work for you?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Header {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow; /* Just to show the area */
}
```

```html
<section class="Header">
  <h1 class="mainHeader">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet con</h1>
  <h3 class="subHeader">obcaecati laboriosam iste ad exercitationem culpa aspernatur, molestias</h3>
</section>
<p>This content is after the header</p>
```